# помогите отредактировать

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Переступая порог, каждый гость попадает в ощущение волшебства."

Comment: Я бы заменил "ощущение" на "атмосферу".

Comment: @VictorBazarov - Викт**о**р, вынесите этот свой комментарий в ответ: он вполне достоин быть им, и лучшим, вместо имеющегося уже многословной переделки

Answer (score 4):

Переступая порог, каждый гость попадает в таинственное магическое пространство, наполненное предвкушением  чуда, тайны, волшебства.

Comment: Пространство может быть наполнено предвкушением?!

Comment: А особую ментальность пространства  как обозначить в речи, как бы вы ее обозначили ? Атмосфера волшебства?  Что-то не очень нравится мне это сочетание, хотя оно  скромненькое и со вкусом. Этот ТЕХНИЧЕСКИЙ термин в переносном смысле используется часто (атмосфера добра, атмосфера влюбленности), но давно уже утерял   свежесть метафоры. Хочется сказать по-другому, обойтись без "атмосферы". Вот пример из художественной литературы: "Ничего особенного не происходило, но предвкушение волшебства странным образом витало в воздухе".

Comment: Действительно, "атмосфера" - это уже избитая метафора.

Comment: Вера, ваш пример из художественной литературы – совсем другое дело. Там нет пространства и нет этих однородных чуда и волшебства.

Comment: "Предвкушение витает в воздухе" - это нормально, а "пространство наполнено предвкушением" вам уже не нравится. И где же ваш вариант (только без атмосферы).

Comment: А у меня нету варианта... Я не умею писать стихи, но умею отличить Пушкина от Пупкина, к примеру.

Comment: Тогда остановимся на "атмосфере" - в конце концов, чем мы хуже других (я думаю, многие будут не против). У "атмосферы" разнообразные возможности: она создает и она создается, она может царить, наполнять воздух и в нее можно даже окунуться, вот послушайте:

Comment: Поговорим о том, как создать атмосферу волшебства и новогоднего чуда . Атмосферу волшебства арфа создает в балетах «Щелкунчик» и «Спящая красавица». Атмосфера волшебства наполняет воздух. Царит какая то необычная атмосфера волшебства. Печи для кухни из кирпича – атмосфера волшебства в вашем доме Попав в зимний сад, мы окунулись в атмосферу сказки и волшебства. Иными словами, атмосфера волшебства везде и всюду.

Comment: Ну и что? Ну – штамп.

Comment: Штамп - это и есть "хорошо и со вкусом"?